# Can I control the generation of UVs on geometry genertated by curves?

Tags: bezier-curves

I've been getting into using blenders curves to generate hair and other long tentacle-like shapes.  I'm finding I'm running into problems with UV mapping.  By default, the generated mesh has UVs that map to the {{0, 0} - {1, 1}} square.  While this is fine if your hair texture is a single independent image, it can cause problems if your hair texture is part of an atlas (for example, when you're creating a texture for an entire character to be exported for a game and you want to have a single texture map for the entire character).

One work around is to convert curve geometry to a mesh, but this is destructive.  Another is to use the Texture Space properties of the curve, but this does not seem to do anything useful (best I can tell, it uses the bounding box of the curve to do a cube projection to create generated UVs, which you then need to add to your shader using an Input/Texture Coordinate node.  The generated UVs are neither useful nor exportable).

Is there some way I could apply a simple transform to the UVs of the generated geometry in local space?  That would let me position my texture map correctly without having to convert it to a mesh.

Comment: You can use a mapping node in your materials, but that's cumbersome and not going to export.  An alternative is to use mesh objects with curve modifiers instead of straight curves.  That lets you do almost anything you can do with a curve (and what's left, won't export anyways), and gives you a way to control UV or other vertex data like vertex color or weights.

Comment: Mesh object with curve modifiers is what I'm doing now.  Unfortunately, they're harder to use since you need to make sure that your mesh and curve objects always have their original lined up.  It becomes really chaotic if you have multiple objects near each other.  You also lose the ability to use the geometry of the bevel and taper objects.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not going to say they're an ideal solution, they're not.  But there are workarounds for your problems.  I parent both my curve and curve-deformed mesh to an empty, then transform lock the curve and mesh, and never, ever move the first control of the curve.  I rarely care about bevel or taper for these, because the mesh lets me control these factors much more carefully than a curve would anyways (yay for proportional editing), but if it's important, it's possible to set a mesh object up to get its shape from bevel+taper objects via more curve modifiers.  Not ideal, but doable.